# Do I need to know SQL when I work with Django

Tags: python, sql, django

I am directing this question to experienced, Django developers, so as in subject, I have been learning Django since September 2016, but I've started to learn it without any knowledge about databases syntax. I know basic concepts and definitions, so I can easily implement in Django models. Summarizing, have I to know SQL to create web apps in Django? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Django abstracts a lot making this possible; however I'm pretty sure your model/view code would benefit from your knowledge of relational DB design and SQL.

Comment: in actually as long as your app didn't have many data, you don't have to learn SQL or Databases Languages, you can work with Django without any knowledge of it. anyway if you don't like to work with DBs you can check    json.

Comment: Generally I am curious, about if professional Django Developer can totally avoid learning SQL?

Comment: You could definitely do so, but don't expect a good and normalized database structure. That's for relational DB at least.

Comment: You can get by without it but I wouldn't. Its very easy to learn. 4 basic commands. Select, Update, Insert, Delete. It is abstracted but you still need to know how a database should be structured to make your models. Your models are equal to your tables. How your data is structured and laid out is just as important as if you were using a raw DB. In Django you are encouraged to stay away from the database as much as possible. Using the ORM is easier if you know SQL and then you'll know what to look for in the ORM. You know what type of query you want to generate and how to do it efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to be a wizard at it but understanding relations between data sets can be extremely helpful especially if you have a complicated data hierarchy.

Just learn as you go. If you want you can look at the SQL code Django executes for you in the migrations.py file of each app.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, yes. Of course the Django ORM will do most of the job for you when it comes to queries, but you should know SQL. Maybe not every single aspect of SQL but enough to now what you're doing.

For instance how can you join two or more tables if you don't know what a join is?
Or given a query, can you improve it and make it more efficient?

Moreover knowing what a relational database is and how to make one, will help you build better and more efficient database, so your application will work better, and will be easier to mantain.
So yes, between knowing and not knowing, always go for knowing!

Have a look at this if you wanna practice a bit:
https://sqlbolt.com/